# Mark photo as a Favorite in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

How can I somehow "grade" or "favorite" my photos in Google Photos?

I take a lot of photos and have a hard time deleting them. :(
So I "Thin The Herd" by marking maybe 1% as favorites.

How can I do this in Google Photo?
They are already arranged in Albums, so I'd rather not do this with a "Favorites" Album. (The Albums are by event/subject.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is life since mid 2018:

https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/21/google-photos-adds-likes-and-favorites-with-hearts-and-stars/

BUT: Its not possible to "favorite" images in an album: Its possible to "favorite" the image itself, but not as a referenced file in an album. Its quite limited. Come on Google, you can do better! (And should do)

Answer (score 1):

Found this question in Sep 2017 (five years after the original question was asked).   Apparently there is not such a feature (as of Mar 2016, that is).  Please see this discussion on Google's product forum

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/gbWTw9hQWak